# Hiding text and displaying some other text on hover

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So, i was having this problem, that i am not able to display text at same position,where i am hiding the text on hover. I AM A NEWBIE, so please dont mock my question, i have just started learning bootstrap.

Here is my code:
html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <title>BOOTProf</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid" style="background-color: deepskyblue;height: 200px;">
    <div id="heading" class="row align-items-center" style="height: 200px;">
        <div id="one" class="col align-self-center" style="background-color: aquamarine;text-align: center;">
            <p class="one">CODING BLOCKS</p>
        </div>
        <div id="two" class="col align-self-center" style="background-color: aquamarine;text-align: center;">
            <p class="two">Come Fall in Love With Coding...</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#heading {
    font-size:450%;
    font-family:Pacifico,cursive;
    color:#fc4c4f;
    margin:0;
}

#heading #two{
    visibility: hidden;
}
#heading:hover #one{
    visibility: hidden;
}
#heading:hover #two{
    visibility: visible;
}
```

The, thing is that i want to display both text in center, but whats happening is that both the text are taking space each on page even when any of them is hidden or not, I want them to take same place on page and dont take extra columns while they are hidden.

Do i have to take help of JS? if yes, then please guide me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `display: none` to remove elements completely from DOM, so that it won't affect other elements' positions:

```
#heading #two{
    display: none;
}
#heading:hover #one{
    display: none;
}
#heading:hover #two{
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Yes, it is saying to wait for 5 mins, before accepting,can we add transition and transform to display property?    @Rax

Comment: @LohitakshTrehan What do you want to achieve? Do you want the element to fade in/out or other animations? If so, you can see other SO answers about that, or post another question if you like.

Answer (score 1):

If **vissible** property set to hidden, it means it is element in body but just not apper in screen, its with , height ....etc properties apply to that element. So use display: block or none.

```
#heading #two{
    display: none;
}
#heading:hover #one{
    display: none;
}
#heading:hover #two{
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change following css and try,

```
#heading {
    font-size:450%;
    font-family:Pacifico,cursive;
    color:#fc4c4f;
    margin:0;
}

#heading #two{
    visibility: hidden;
}
#heading:hover #one{
    visibility: hidden;
}
#heading:hover #two{
    visibility: visible;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Or, check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/ea27gdk4/) fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <title>BOOTProf</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid" style="background-color: deepskyblue;height: 200px;" id="heading">  
        <div id="one" class="col " style="background-color: aquamarine;text-align: center;">
CODING BLOCKS
        </div>
        <div id="two" class="col" style="background-color: aquamarine;text-align: center;">
            Come Fall in Love With Coding...
        </div>
   
</div>
<style>
#heading {
    font-size:450%;
    font-family:Pacifico,cursive;
    color:#fc4c4f;
    margin:0;
}

#heading #two{
    visibility: hidden;
}
#heading:hover #one{
    visibility: hidden;
}
#heading:hover #two{
    visibility: visible;
}
</style>
```

Hope, this solves your question.